# Wald Statistic and Confidence Region

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

[image]

---

I don't understand the conclusion in green here. I take it as to mean that if the hypothesis were correct the approximate 95% CR for $a \choose b$ is what has been underlined in red. However, how can

$\frac{25}{8}(a_0 -\frac{4}{5})^2+\frac{16}{1}(b_0 - \frac{1}{4})^2$

have an approximate chi-squared distribution when there is nothing random about it. The paramater $a \choose b$ is an unknown constant?

Answer (score 2):

All other CIs we have seen everyday are like this. Note that in the previous step it has shown you the formula of $W^*(a_0, b_0)$ which is in terms of $\hat{a}, \hat{b}$ which is indeed random, before we got the realization of them (observe them through data).

So all CIs, including this one, are using a random interval to bound a deterministic parameter (in frequentist setting). However, after observing the data, people will plug in the observed value to the confidence limit, and you got a point estimate of the limit. So the resulting numbers is just a realization, and same as all other CI, after plugging in the numbers you can no longer say that the probability that the deterministic true parameter inside this deterministic region is some numbers other than $0$ or $1$.